# Changing textview inside Cardview

Tags: android, kotlin

I am stuck in my android project and I hope someone would give time to check it.

I have a recyclerview populated by cardviews. Each cardview has Textview in it.

What I am trying to accomplish is for each cardview, i want to change their textview.text based on the button clicked.

```
for(card in cardList){
   val textView = card.findViewWithTag("TEXT_VIEW") as TextView
   //get button click
   //change text
}
```

EDITED:
I have this following code:

```
for(card in cardList){
   //get the textview inside
  card.findViewWithTag("TEXT_VIEW") as TextView
  //set onclick listener for all buttons
  for(button in buttons){
    button.setOnClickListener{
        tv.text = button.text
   }
}
```

But what happening is if I click a button, all textviews within the cardviews will change to the button.text

What I wanted to do is if I click a button, It will only change the textview of the first cardview, then click a button again and change the textview of the second cardview's textview and soon.

Please do refer to the image attached.
Thank you and I hope that you're all doing great this pandemic.

[number-sorter-app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAh3f.jpg)

Comment: you didn't mention what exactly you are stuck in?

Comment: you should post more code and explanation, also define properly your problem, it isn't clear what do you want to achieve (screen isn't sufficient)

Comment: I am so sorry. Please refer to the post. I edited it. Got too excited to post the question without further explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do exactly, but maybe you mean something like that:

Make variable which will said which index of cardList texview should be filled:

```
val textViewIndexToFill = 0
```

And then when you want fill textview one by one you should do something like that (based on yours code):

```
var txtView = cardList[textViewIndexToFill].findViewWithTag("TEXT_VIEW") as TextView
for(button in buttons) {
button.setOnClickListener{
   txtView.text = button.text
   textViewIndexToFill++
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. I would happily try this one. BTW, my project goes like this. User will set how many numbers he wanted to sort. Then from that value, the next activity will display the recyclerview in which the number of cards is based on the user's input. The recyclerview will then display the cardviews with empty textview. Then the user will then populate it using buttons. Sorry if I am making you confused in someways but all your helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: So maybe remember to do something like that: 
button.setOnClickListener{
if( textViewIndexToFill < cardList.size){
   txtView.text = button.text
   textViewIndexToFill++ }
}
to not get "index out of range" error.